# How do I enter a record for every user where condition is true in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have app that has political candidates.

When a new political candidate is entered, I want to enter a notification into the notifications table for every user that's state is equal to the state of the new candidate being entered.

Ultimately, I want to enter in records to the notification table for every single user where that condition is met.

I know I'm way off, but here's where I'm at now. I'm trying to loop through each user and then enter this record when that condition is true.

```
  def create
    @candidate = Candidate.new(candidate_params)
    if @candidate.save
      User.each do |u|
        if Candidate.state == User.state
          @notification = Notification.new(:message => 'Message', :user_id => U.id)
          @notification.save
        else 
        end
      end
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end
```

The candidate is created with this code, but the notifications aren't working. Basically I have two users where their state equals "Arizona" and I would expect if I create a new candidate where the state is "Arizona" that I should get two record into notifications, one with each user ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got a bit mixed up between classes and instances. Here's the relevant bit:

```
@candidate = Candidate.new(candidate_params)
...
User.each do |u|
  if Candidate.state == User.state
      ...
  end
end
```

In your code `Candidate` is a class, and `@candidate` holds the recently created instance of a Candidate. Likewise, `User` is a class and `u` holds a User instance (on each loop iteration). Your comparison should actually use the instances rather than the classes:

```
if @candidate.state == u.state
```

Having sorted that, it's worth noting that your code has a couple of other errors -- `User.each` won't work. You need to specify a selector to get a list of `User` objects to loop through. One way would be to call `User.all.each` (which looking at your code is probably what you were trying). That pulls all `User` objects. But, since users can be from anywhere, if you do that you will cycle through a lot of users you don't need to.

Since all you need is users whose state matches the new candidate, you can use the `where()` method to pre-filter the list you are looping through. That way you don't need the `if` at all.

```
@candidate = Candidate.new(candidate_params)
...
User.where(state: @candidate.state).each do |u|
  @notification = Notification.new(message: 'Message', user: u)
  @notification.save
end
```

The other problem in your code is in the line to create a notification. You use `U.id` but the loop variable is lower case `u`. As an added tip, you don't need to set the object ID specifically. If you just pass the `User` object (as in the code above), Rails is smart enough to figure out the rest.

Comment: You are a scholar and a saint. This worked beautifully. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For performance don't iterate all users, you can search users that match the candidate's state then create notification for each user.

```
def create
  @candidate = Candidate.new(candidate_params)
  if @candidate.save
    users = User.where(state: @condidate.state)
    users.each { |user| @notification = Notification.create(:message => 'Message', :user_id =user.id } if users
    else
       render 'new'
    end
end
```